# why mysql explain says 'using index' while the index used do not contain required fields

Tags: mysql, innodb

Here is the output of an explain command in mysql(innodb):

```
explain select * from multi_index_test_tbl_1 force index(`query_index_1`) where `text_field1`='0' order by `numeric_field2` desc limit 1000000;
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | multi_index_test_tbl_1 | ref  | query_index_1 | query_index_1 | 386     | const | 53547628 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

The schema of table `multi_index_test_tbl_1` is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `multi_index_test_tbl_1` 
(
    `text_field1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `numeric_field1` float NOT NULL,
    `numeric_field2` float NOT NULL,
    `text_field2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`text_field1`,`numeric_field1`,`text_field2`),
    KEY `query_index_1` (`text_field1`,`numeric_field2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It seems that `query_index_1` is used. And 'using index' appears in `Extra` while the index `query_index_1` doesn't contain all fields in table `multi_index_test_tbl_1`.

Since mysql doc says that:

> Using index (JSON property: using_index)
>
> The column information is retrieved from the table **using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row**. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index.

I'm confused what's exactly happening here.

Comment: @zerkms mysql doc says that `using index` means columns are retrieved using `only information in the index`

Comment: why are you not showing the table schema? Why are you forcing the index then wondering why it is saying "ok I will use that index"

Comment: @Drew sorry, i've added the schema. But the question is: according to the official doc, `using index` not only indicates that the index is used, but also means that the actual row(thus the clustered index) is not used.

Comment: You realize that half the info returned by `explain` is borderline fantasy land sometimes. You are asking a routine to within a split second, return info to us impatient consumers of it. And in that split second determine its alleged plan. One that it can happily deviate from when actually run. And that that execution might take up to 10 hours to run (when not using `explain` but actually run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, but it does 'contain required fields'.  To elaborate...

InnoDB includes all the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY` in each 'secondary' index.  So,

```
KEY `query_index_1` (`text_field1`,`numeric_field2`)
```

is really more like

```
KEY `query_index_1` (`text_field1`,`numeric_field2`,
                     `numeric_field1`,`text_field2`)
```

In your example, that includes all the columns.  Hence, everything in the `SELECT`, including `*` is found in that secondary index.  So, "Using index" is 'correct'.

This is one way in which InnoDB is sometimes better than MyISAM.

Try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to get more details.

Comment: this is the answer! i've confirmed it by experiments on some test tables.